# JSX element attribute not changing with onChange

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, onchange

I have JSX element in my React code with value attribute which is not changing correctly with onChange method. 
First I am using React Hooks:

```
  const [isBusiness, setIsBusiness] = useState(false);
```

I am using this constant in my JSX:

```
               <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  value={isBusiness} //here is the constant
                  id="isBusiness"
                  onChange={businessChange}
                  name="check"
                />
```

My onChange method is like this:

```
  const businessChange = e => {
    if (e.target.value == true) {
      console.log(isBusiness);

      setIsBusiness(false);
    } else {
      console.log(isBusiness);

      setIsBusiness(true);
    }
  };
```

I am seeing what happens and it is stucking at true for some reason:

[image]

The idea is to be able to get value of this checkbox (true or false) if it is clicked or not. The initial value is false.

Comment: What about using `.checked`?

Answer (score 3):

You can set it proper and simple without using the `event`

```
  const businessChange = () => {
    setIsBusiness(!isBusiness);
  };
```

```js
const App = () => {
  const [isBusiness, setIsBusiness] = React.useState(false);
  const businessChange = () => {
    console.log(!isBusiness);
    setIsBusiness(!isBusiness);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value={isBusiness} //here is the constant
        id="isBusiness"
        onChange={businessChange}
        name="check"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @evolutionxbox - No. :-)

Answer (score 3):

`e.target.value == true` will always be false, because `e.target.value` is a **string**. Your `isBusiness` will be converted to `"true"` or `"false"`, and both `"true" == true` and `"false" == true` are false.

Typically, you rarely use `value` with checkboxes, and only use `value` with checkboxes if you're submitting a form somewhere; it provides the value to send (by default it's `"on"`). Instead, use `checked`:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={isBusiness}
    id="isBusiness"
    onChange={businessChange}
    name="check"
/>
```

Then

```
const businessChange = e => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      console.log(isBusiness);
      setIsBusiness(true);
    } else {
      console.log(isBusiness);
      setIsBusiness(false);
    }
};
```

Or simply:

```
const businessChange = e => {
    console.log(isBusiness);
    setIsBusiness(e.target.checked);
};
```

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [isBusiness, setIsBusiness] = useState(false);

    const businessChange = e => {
        console.log(isBusiness);
        setIsBusiness(e.target.checked);
    };

    return (
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={isBusiness}
            id="isBusiness"
            onChange={businessChange}
            name="check"
        />
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Note:** It's slightly confusing with the logging, because you're always logging the *old* value. :-) Here's a version logging the **new** value:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [isBusiness, setIsBusiness] = useState(false);

    const businessChange = e => {
        console.log(e.target.checked);
        setIsBusiness(e.target.checked);
    };

    return (
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={isBusiness}
            id="isBusiness"
            onChange={businessChange}
            name="check"
        />
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

I would lean, however, toward not using the checkbox flag at all in the handler, as shown [by keikai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60848514/157247) though they don't show correct setting of the checkbox. Here's a version logging the new value (not the old):

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [isBusiness, setIsBusiness] = useState(false);

    const businessChange = e => {
        console.log(!isBusiness);
        setIsBusiness(!isBusiness);
    };

    return (
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={isBusiness}
            id="isBusiness"
            onChange={businessChange}
            name="check"
        />
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the very answer SO needs. Nice job